# opendnssec and DelegationSignerSubmitCommand

Tags: domain-name-system, dnssec

I have a zone `myzone.fr` on my DNS running BIND and opendnssec. The new DS need to be send to the registry as shown in the log of `ods-enforcerd`:

> ods-enforcerd: WARNING: New KSK has reached the ready state; please submit the DS for myzone.fr and use ods-ksmutil key ds-seen when the DS appears in the DNS.

According to the openddnssec documentation, I'm using the `<DelegationSignerSubmitCommand />` located in the conf.xml to run a script that should send me the list of the zones with ready KSK.

For my tests, I'm using the [simple-dnskey-mailer.sh](https://github.com/opendnssec/opendnssec/tree/develop/plugins/simple-dnskey-mailer) script. But the script doesn't start.

What are the conditions for this command to fire up?

Thanks for your answers